# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed on 404

Tags: java, spring, glassfish

I have a Spring 4.0.1 Java Web Application deployed on Glassfish 4.0. Whenever a 404 error occurs, there's an exception thrown in the logs. The error page is shown correctly  (it's plain, simple html). Even though the application works fine, I'd like to get rid of this exception. This exception IS NOT thrown when running localy on tomcat.

Error page config in web.xml:

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/pages/404.html</location>
</error-page>

<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Throwable</exception-type>
    <location>/pages/500.html</location>
</error-page>
```

Location points to html files in resources.

Full stack:

```
[2015-09-28T12:11:39.092+0200] [glassfish 4.0] [WARNING] [] [javax.enterprise.web] [tid: _ThreadID=1126 _ThreadName=http-listener-3(28)] [timeMillis: 1443435099092] [levelValue: 900] [[



org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve@bd9e709: Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/pages/404.html]

org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:695)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:492)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:691)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:376)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:234)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)

at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:448)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.java:122)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)

... 33 more

----- Root Cause -----

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doDispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:448)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.dispatch(ApplicationDispatcher.java:428)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:378)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(DefaultServletHttpRequestHandler.java:122)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.handle(HttpRequestHandlerAdapter.java:51)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:945)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:876)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:961)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:852)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)

at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:837)

at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInvoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:875)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:739)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doInclude(ApplicationDispatcher.java:695)

at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.include(ApplicationDispatcher.java:626)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:492)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.dispatchToErrorPage(StandardHostValve.java:691)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:376)

at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.postInvoke(StandardHostValve.java:234)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)

at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)

at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)

at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

]]
```

Comment: I have the same problem with a jsf 2.3 application running on Payara (glassfish). I use primefaces 6.2 and omnifaces 2.7

Answer (score 0):

This exception often occurs whenever you try to do a forward or a redirect after you already did once. Based on my experience, you probably have somewhere in your code an `if` instruction with a redirect and afterwards another forward/redirect. If that's the case, just add an else clause before the second redirect. If this is not the problem, please can you post some more code?

Comment: Thanks but I already read thousands of such answers ;) Nothing like that anywhere in my code and the error occurs on page not found error which is handled by spring.

Comment: Also, I don't really know what code I should post. The stack trace doesn't point to any spot in particular but "Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=404, location=/pages/404.html]".

Comment: Are you using an IDE? Try to debug with it. So you can see where exactly the exception is thrown and then you can post that here.